# Drawing a logo in LaTeX to be incorporated as header

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

Is it possible to draw [this image](http://www.123freevectors.com/medical-symbol-vector/) using LaTeX so that it can be incorporated in letterhead as a logo:

[image]

Comment: This is already a vector image. Why don't you just include it? Otherwise you can try drawing it in something like inkscape, etc. Tikz is possible, but is going to take a while I assume.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but as @Markus says: why redo the work? You can include this figure directly in a LaTeX document.  Including it with `\includegraphics{med.eps}` (assuming it's in your current directory) and compiling with `--shell-escape` will automatically convert to PDF

Comment: There is [inkscape2tikz](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/)....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>This is cheating!</sub>

As commented by jon you can use [inkscape2tikz](https://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{c100f0d}{RGB}{16,115,13}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[cm={{1.25,0.0,0.0,-1.25,(0.0,665.2125)}}]
  \begin{scope}[scale=0.100]
        \path[fill=c100f0d,nonzero rule] (3355.5800,4179.9000) .. controls
          (3355.5800,4192.7600) and (3345.1400,4203.1900) .. (3332.2700,4203.1900) ..
          controls (3319.3900,4203.1900) and (3308.9600,4192.7600) ..
          (3308.9600,4179.9000) .. controls (3308.9600,4167.0200) and
          (3319.3900,4156.5900) .. (3332.2700,4156.5900) .. controls
          (3345.1400,4156.5900) and (3355.5800,4167.0200) ..
          (3355.5800,4179.9000)(4000.9900,3636.5100) .. controls (3992.4800,3573.9800)
          and (3968.0100,3512.3700) .. (3933.5800,3461.4400) .. controls
          (3860.3100,3364.6600) and (3774.7500,3297.6900) .. (3682.6000,3250.8100) ..
          controls (3623.9600,3288.4500) and (3560.5800,3319.0900) ..
          (3496.7400,3346.7000) .. controls (3441.9300,3370.4300) and
          (3384.5000,3397.6200) .. (3326.4300,3412.1300) .. controls
          (3319.0600,3413.9800) and (3311.6500,3415.4700) .. (3304.2700,3416.8800) ..
          controls (3308.0700,3417.4900) and (3311.8100,3418.0100) ..
          (3315.6300,3418.6800) .. controls (3482.9700,3445.3600) and
          (3643.5800,3516.6500) .. (3701.3900,3608.7600) .. controls
          (3731.3300,3649.7300) and (3732.9800,3696.8400) .. (3726.9300,3762.8700) ..
          controls (3718.3400,3819.7500) and (3707.4900,3897.7100) ..
          (3671.0700,3927.9400) .. controls (3514.4600,4098.4500) and
          (3446.3100,3971.6900) .. (3324.8900,3978.4300) .. controls
          (3251.4600,3981.1200) and (3090.2100,4019.0700) .. (3089.9500,4096.8800) ..
          controls (3141.5600,4177.1900) and (3263.8300,4262.1300) ..
          (3340.4200,4259.0500) .. controls (3486.1700,4245.4200) and
          (3661.6900,4238.6200) .. (3839.9200,4100.8900) .. controls
          (3927.7800,4031.1700) and (3989.4100,3913.4000) .. (4001.5400,3802.8600) ..
          controls (4007.5200,3745.0200) and (4010.5800,3700.7100) ..
          (4000.9900,3636.5100)(2693.3900,4179.9000) .. controls (2693.3900,4167.0200)
          and (2703.8200,4156.5900) .. (2716.6900,4156.5900) .. controls
          (2729.5600,4156.5900) and (2740.0000,4167.0200) .. (2740.0000,4179.9000) ..
          controls (2740.0000,4192.7600) and (2729.5600,4203.1900) ..
          (2716.6900,4203.1900) .. controls (2703.8200,4203.1900) and
          (2693.3900,4192.7600) .. (2693.3900,4179.9000)(3807.8400,2817.9100) ..
          controls (3804.0500,2739.6400) and (3769.3400,2659.9200) ..
          (3720.9500,2604.1400) .. controls (3672.5000,2547.9300) and
          (3616.0400,2510.1100) .. (3559.9200,2480.5600) .. controls
          (3559.6700,2480.4100) and (3559.3700,2480.2800) .. (3559.0700,2480.1300) ..
          controls (3476.7600,2550.5300) and (3374.4700,2598.9900) ..
          (3268.0300,2625.6800) .. controls (3430.5400,2659.8800) and
          (3578.6100,2751.3000) .. (3563.9400,2841.7000) .. controls
          (3566.1900,2986.7600) and (3433.9100,3073.1400) .. (3256.8300,3109.0000) ..
          controls (2939.1400,3171.5300) and (2419.2300,3057.5100) ..
          (2113.3500,3461.4400) .. controls (2078.9500,3512.3700) and
          (2054.4600,3573.9800) .. (2045.9900,3636.5100) .. controls
          (2036.3700,3700.7100) and (2039.4400,3745.0200) .. (2045.3900,3802.8600) ..
          controls (2057.5400,3913.4000) and (2119.1500,4031.1700) ..
          (2207.0200,4100.8900) .. controls (2385.2500,4238.6200) and
          (2560.7900,4245.4200) .. (2706.5300,4259.0500) .. controls
          (2783.1300,4262.1300) and (2905.4100,4177.1900) .. (2957.0000,4096.8800) ..
          controls (2956.9500,4083.6000) and (2952.2200,4071.5000) ..
          (2944.0600,4060.5300) .. controls (2904.3100,4007.1400) and
          (2782.9600,3980.6700) .. (2722.0500,3978.4300) .. controls
          (2600.6300,3971.6900) and (2532.4800,4098.4500) .. (2375.8900,3927.9400) ..
          controls (2339.4600,3897.7100) and (2328.6100,3819.7500) ..
          (2320.0200,3762.8700) .. controls (2313.9800,3696.8400) and
          (2315.6300,3649.7300) .. (2345.5500,3608.7600) .. controls
          (2403.3500,3516.6500) and (2563.9900,3445.3600) .. (2731.3000,3418.6800) ..
          controls (2818.7700,3403.4300) and (2900.5500,3400.2200) ..
          (3003.1600,3397.2200) .. controls (3107.8200,3393.8000) and
          (3215.4500,3384.3400) .. (3326.0400,3357.6000) .. controls
          (3435.4500,3329.6100) and (3552.6500,3287.8100) .. (3654.4300,3196.3800) ..
          controls (3759.6500,3106.9300) and (3818.4600,2956.4700) ..
          (3807.8400,2817.9100)(3019.6200,4858.2600) .. controls (2948.0500,4855.1800)
          and (2885.6600,4897.2500) .. (2865.9300,4878.4300) .. controls
          (2843.1800,4862.1900) and (2900.6400,4749.8000) .. (3019.6200,4749.2200) ..
          controls (3138.6000,4749.8000) and (3196.0600,4862.2000) ..
          (3173.3200,4878.4300) .. controls (3153.5800,4897.2500) and
          (3091.2000,4855.1800) .. (3019.6200,4858.2600)(3019.6200,5321.7200) ..
          controls (2897.3500,5321.7200) and (2798.2600,5222.6100) ..
          (2798.2600,5100.3500) .. controls (2798.2600,4978.0800) and
          (2897.3500,4878.9700) .. (3019.6200,4878.9700) .. controls
          (3141.8700,4878.9700) and (3241.0000,4978.0800) .. (3241.0000,5100.3500) ..
          controls (3241.0000,5222.6100) and (3141.8700,5321.7200) ..
          (3019.6200,5321.7200)(2978.8600,646.6410) .. controls (2990.5700,245.6800) and
          (3004.2400,-8.6719) .. (3019.6200,0.2188) .. controls (3029.6500,6.0195) and
          (3040.7900,257.0900) .. (3051.7100,646.6410) -- (2978.8600,646.6410) --
          cycle(3056.1500,813.6480) .. controls (3058.6700,913.1480) and
          (3061.1900,1019.4200) .. (3063.6500,1131.1400) -- (2966.9900,1131.1400) ..
          controls (2969.3300,1019.4200) and (2971.7800,913.1680) ..
          (2974.3100,813.6480) -- (3056.1500,813.6480) -- cycle(3068.1500,1343.7900) ..
          controls (3070.7100,1468.6300) and (3073.2000,1598.6400) ..
          (3075.6100,1732.1400) -- (2956.1800,1732.1400) .. controls
          (2958.2500,1598.6600) and (2960.4700,1468.6600) .. (2962.8000,1343.7900) --
          (3068.1500,1343.7900) -- cycle(2947.7800,2339.0000) .. controls
          (2949.3800,2208.8000) and (2951.0700,2079.5500) .. (2952.8800,1952.5500) --
          (3079.4700,1952.5500) .. controls (3081.6200,2079.5300) and
          (3083.6900,2208.8000) .. (3085.6500,2339.0000) -- (2947.7800,2339.0000) --
          cycle(2939.9100,3085.6400) .. controls (2941.2000,2940.5100) and
          (2942.6400,2793.4600) .. (2944.2400,2646.3000) -- (3090.1400,2646.3000) ..
          controls (3092.1900,2793.4200) and (3094.1000,2940.4800) ..
          (3095.8300,3085.6400) -- (2939.9100,3085.6400) -- cycle(3019.6200,4410.0000)
          -- (3107.5600,4573.1200) .. controls (3107.6400,4606.5400) and
          (3107.6500,4639.2900) .. (3107.6500,4670.7400) .. controls
          (3107.6500,4714.7300) and (3068.2200,4734.2900) .. (3019.6200,4734.2900) ..
          controls (2971.0300,4734.2900) and (2931.5900,4721.2900) ..
          (2931.5900,4670.7400) .. controls (2931.5900,4639.3200) and
          (2931.6100,4606.5600) .. (2931.6500,4573.1200) -- (3019.6200,4410.0000) --
          cycle(3019.0800,4136.2000) -- (2933.7800,3938.1300) .. controls
          (2934.6200,3782.2400) and (2935.6500,3618.1200) .. (2936.9100,3448.7800) --
          (3099.9200,3448.7800) .. controls (3101.6600,3618.0200) and
          (3103.1600,3782.1300) .. (3104.3500,3938.1300) -- (3019.0800,4136.2000) --
          cycle(3482.2900,2468.6000) .. controls (3378.6800,2554.4500) and
          (3253.8800,2585.7900) .. (3139.8200,2596.8100) .. controls
          (3016.4900,2605.5900) and (2932.0700,2598.1900) .. (2837.1300,2615.9600) ..
          controls (2653.8500,2638.1000) and (2466.6100,2740.5600) ..
          (2483.0200,2841.7000) .. controls (2481.0800,2966.5300) and
          (2578.8300,3047.8900) .. (2718.9800,3091.0100) .. controls
          (2607.2000,3105.0600) and (2497.6200,3131.0100) .. (2393.4300,3180.8500) ..
          controls (2389.4300,3182.7600) and (2385.8500,3184.9400) ..
          (2382.5100,3187.2800) .. controls (2283.6900,3096.9600) and
          (2228.8600,2951.9500) .. (2239.1200,2817.9100) .. controls
          (2242.8900,2739.6400) and (2277.6100,2659.9200) .. (2326.0000,2604.1400) ..
          controls (2374.4500,2547.9300) and (2430.9200,2510.1100) ..
          (2487.0200,2480.5600) .. controls (2600.1700,2422.6000) and
          (2715.0600,2398.3100) .. (2828.9500,2384.1000) .. controls
          (2944.3400,2368.8400) and (3061.7700,2382.0200) .. (3142.6300,2373.0100) ..
          controls (3230.8600,2364.3500) and (3310.9900,2337.9500) ..
          (3360.2800,2291.4200) .. controls (3409.5000,2249.6700) and
          (3434.4500,2169.0200) .. (3432.0000,2102.4400) .. controls
          (3429.4800,2049.4200) and (3387.8500,2006.7700) .. (3311.4200,1975.8400) ..
          controls (3287.6500,1966.4200) and (3262.0300,1959.1500) ..
          (3235.5100,1953.3500) .. controls (3315.1100,1921.9700) and
          (3388.6500,1876.3000) .. (3466.1600,1833.7500) .. controls
          (3503.6000,1855.7700) and (3539.8700,1884.4000) .. (3570.2000,1922.9500) ..
          controls (3614.9300,1978.3000) and (3638.2800,2054.3300) ..
          (3637.0300,2122.0900) .. controls (3638.5500,2244.8200) and
          (3588.0000,2382.4800) .. (3482.2900,2468.6000)(3361.6700,1022.3700) ..
          controls (3362.1500,1109.3700) and (3301.3800,1207.1500) ..
          (3216.5900,1248.1300) .. controls (3138.8700,1293.7100) and
          (3031.4700,1297.6000) .. (2967.5000,1308.8500) .. controls
          (2895.7400,1322.1300) and (2825.0000,1352.9600) .. (2774.2900,1399.5800) ..
          controls (2723.4500,1448.8700) and (2700.9100,1502.1400) ..
          (2719.9300,1569.6500) .. controls (2733.6800,1626.6300) and
          (2765.1600,1673.6300) .. (2812.7700,1704.6500) .. controls
          (2798.8900,1707.1900) and (2785.0200,1709.8800) .. (2771.2900,1713.6000) ..
          controls (2722.3000,1726.8800) and (2676.7300,1748.1300) ..
          (2629.4000,1765.3200) .. controls (2583.6800,1703.2700) and
          (2556.8100,1628.5300) .. (2551.9500,1558.8000) .. controls
          (2538.6900,1425.5700) and (2622.6600,1311.5200) .. (2708.9100,1256.2500) ..
          controls (2797.1400,1197.1700) and (2893.6800,1170.9400) ..
          (2985.8900,1163.3900) .. controls (3070.5800,1159.9100) and
          (3132.5100,1149.2700) .. (3180.4300,1118.2500) .. controls
          (3269.8800,1065.6200) and (3261.7000,907.8790) .. (3179.6700,853.1020) ..
          controls (3149.1900,828.2190) and (3111.5000,809.6720) .. (3072.3500,795.3400)
          .. controls (3114.3300,779.7190) and (3154.9300,761.2380) ..
          (3194.5200,740.3980) .. controls (3221.8000,754.2110) and (3248.9800,772.0200)
          .. (3275.0200,796.0700) .. controls (3334.7800,849.1410) and
          (3367.0800,938.6800) .. (3361.6700,1022.3700)(2871.6000,430.3980) .. controls
          (2860.5400,499.2190) and (2869.3300,591.1210) .. (2945.9200,645.9880) ..
          controls (2951.4100,651.0590) and (2957.5000,655.5120) .. (2964.0500,659.5700)
          .. controls (2936.2300,671.6210) and (2908.6300,684.1020) ..
          (2881.1400,696.8910) .. controls (2876.4500,692.2190) and (2871.8300,687.4690)
          .. (2867.5600,682.4800) .. controls (2826.2300,636.0310) and
          (2806.0800,576.4610) .. (2804.7600,524.6990) .. controls (2803.4700,475.4490)
          and (2810.9500,430.9100) .. (2825.9200,392.4410) .. controls
          (2854.3900,312.1990) and (2924.9300,277.3710) .. (2963.4300,276.0780) ..
          controls (3003.7000,272.2700) and (3021.4400,281.2380) .. (3018.2200,285.4690)
          .. controls (3024.4400,296.0510) and (2896.5400,283.0700) ..
          (2871.6000,430.3980)(3179.4000,682.4800) .. controls (3138.9100,729.6090) and
          (3078.6600,763.9220) .. (3015.1000,781.9690) .. controls (2962.1400,797.7110)
          and (2908.2100,819.6600) .. (2867.2900,853.1020) .. controls
          (2785.2400,907.8790) and (2777.0800,1065.6200) .. (2866.5200,1118.2500) ..
          controls (2874.8800,1123.6400) and (2883.8000,1128.2100) ..
          (2893.0300,1132.4500) .. controls (2845.0500,1149.3200) and
          (2797.5800,1167.9700) .. (2748.8700,1183.6800) .. controls
          (2709.3900,1137.0700) and (2684.9600,1077.5700) .. (2685.2900,1022.3700) ..
          controls (2679.8500,938.6800) and (2712.1700,849.1410) .. (2771.9300,796.0700)
          .. controls (2891.7300,685.3980) and (3035.9600,706.1480) ..
          (3101.0200,645.9880) .. controls (3177.6300,591.1210) and (3186.4000,499.2190)
          .. (3175.3400,430.3980) .. controls (3150.4100,283.0700) and
          (3022.5200,296.0510) .. (3028.7200,285.4690) .. controls (3025.5200,281.2380)
          and (3043.2500,272.2700) .. (3083.5300,276.0780) .. controls
          (3122.0200,277.3710) and (3192.5900,312.1990) .. (3221.0400,392.4410) ..
          controls (3235.9900,430.9100) and (3243.4900,475.4490) .. (3242.2100,524.6990)
          .. controls (3240.8600,576.4610) and (3220.7300,636.0310) ..
          (3179.4000,682.4800)(3201.7300,1722.5100) .. controls (3267.9200,1693.6600)
          and (3310.3300,1638.8000) .. (3327.0200,1569.6500) .. controls
          (3346.0400,1502.1400) and (3323.5200,1448.8700) .. (3272.6600,1399.5800) ..
          controls (3228.3000,1358.8000) and (3168.6200,1330.0900) ..
          (3106.3500,1314.6600) .. controls (3186.4000,1304.9500) and
          (3248.9600,1275.4500) .. (3311.6700,1239.7700) .. controls
          (3320.5200,1244.9800) and (3329.3400,1250.4300) .. (3338.0600,1256.2500) ..
          controls (3424.3000,1311.5200) and (3508.2600,1425.5700) ..
          (3495.0100,1558.8000) .. controls (3487.2800,1669.6800) and
          (3423.9600,1793.2600) .. (3317.5200,1858.3100) .. controls
          (3213.5600,1925.1300) and (3092.5200,1938.2100) .. (2987.9500,1936.3900) ..
          controls (2900.4200,1935.9900) and (2809.7800,1946.4700) ..
          (2735.5400,1975.8400) .. controls (2659.1100,2006.7700) and
          (2617.4900,2049.4200) .. (2614.9500,2102.4400) .. controls
          (2612.5000,2169.0200) and (2637.4500,2249.6700) .. (2686.6600,2291.4200) ..
          controls (2707.7900,2311.3400) and (2734.6100,2327.5600) ..
          (2765.2800,2340.3100) .. controls (2754.9300,2342.9100) and
          (2744.5500,2345.4800) .. (2734.0900,2347.9600) .. controls
          (2659.1200,2365.6500) and (2587.2200,2389.5900) .. (2518.7700,2423.9900) ..
          controls (2444.4000,2339.1600) and (2408.6400,2225.4100) ..
          (2409.9300,2122.0900) .. controls (2408.6700,2054.3300) and
          (2432.0300,1978.3000) .. (2476.7500,1922.9500) .. controls
          (2520.8400,1866.9000) and (2577.4200,1831.4600) .. (2632.0500,1807.5200) ..
          controls (2742.7300,1760.1900) and (2851.6700,1750.7000) ..
          (2956.6100,1750.5900) .. controls (3058.8200,1755.5900) and
          (3132.5800,1753.6800) .. (3201.7300,1722.5100)(3726.2400,5234.3300) ..
          controls (3463.6000,5266.3700) and (3457.7600,5094.5100) ..
          (3457.7600,5012.9600) .. controls (3457.7600,4931.4000) and
          (3552.9400,4528.4600) .. (3129.5900,4528.4600) .. controls
          (3105.3100,4528.4600) and (3017.2200,4333.7100) .. (3035.6500,4340.0900) ..
          controls (3072.5500,4360.4900) and (3154.8300,4340.0900) ..
          (3221.8400,4340.0900) .. controls (3273.7800,4340.0900) and
          (3355.0500,4341.4300) .. (3448.0600,4355.6300) .. controls
          (3461.7700,4357.7300) and (3350.2500,4397.0800) .. (3363.5900,4399.3200) ..
          controls (3376.4700,4401.4800) and (3535.5200,4379.8400) ..
          (3547.7500,4382.0900) .. controls (3580.8800,4413.0600) and
          (3651.9700,4467.3000) .. (3735.8400,4495.4500) .. controls
          (3747.4300,4500.4600) and (3582.4000,4551.3200) .. (3593.2100,4555.6400) ..
          controls (3625.8700,4568.7100) and (3834.8100,4528.6000) ..
          (3851.9800,4532.3400) .. controls (3908.7500,4546.9000) and
          (3945.8800,4605.1000) .. (4018.0600,4642.7500) .. controls
          (4027.8200,4647.8500) and (3811.5500,4711.0000) .. (3827.7100,4720.2100) ..
          controls (3844.1700,4726.3900) and (4092.9000,4674.6400) ..
          (4113.1500,4677.9800) .. controls (4388.9100,4643.0300) and
          (4593.7800,4753.7200) .. (4589.8900,4823.6300) .. controls
          (4436.4800,4925.5800) and (3988.8900,5202.2900) ..
          (3726.2400,5234.3300)(3032.8200,4317.0300) .. controls (3032.8200,4317.0300)
          and (3012.8200,4209.1400) .. (3068.6300,4116.2700) .. controls
          (3097.7500,4160.9600) and (3148.7400,4212.9000) .. (3232.5000,4251.5700) ..
          controls (3211.5100,4268.4400) and (3193.6200,4282.2900) ..
          (3180.0700,4291.5500) .. controls (3135.9100,4321.1600) and
          (3032.8200,4317.0300) .. (3032.8200,4317.0300)(3221.8400,4305.1500) ..
          controls (3221.8400,4305.1500) and (3238.2300,4290.5300) ..
          (3264.9500,4267.6400) .. controls (3402.9200,4316.5300) and
          (3611.6700,4261.4500) .. (3714.3300,4216.3000) .. controls
          (3801.0500,4178.1700) and (3906.1100,4115.8100) .. (3993.4100,3961.6000) ..
          controls (4076.0700,3965.6700) and (4158.7600,3978.2100) ..
          (4230.6400,4000.2700) .. controls (4104.4000,4039.1100) and
          (3634.4800,4285.7200) .. (3560.6900,4340.0900) .. controls
          (3481.0700,4314.8500) and (3221.8400,4305.1500) ..
          (3221.8400,4305.1500)(3593.2100,4356.1200) .. controls (3593.2100,4356.1200)
          and (4017.0300,4098.3400) .. (4240.3600,4031.3400) .. controls
          (4383.2800,3988.4600) and (4701.5400,3949.7800) .. (4855.9200,4089.6000) ..
          controls (4439.4000,4142.0300) and (3967.5100,4412.9100) ..
          (3871.3900,4477.0000) .. controls (3757.7800,4501.7600) and
          (3593.2100,4356.1200) .. (3593.2100,4356.1200)(5505.4800,4238.1600) ..
          controls (5120.9900,4273.1000) and (4448.1300,4477.0000) ..
          (4174.3300,4631.3800) .. controls (4025.7600,4654.6800) and
          (4019.9400,4536.7100) .. (3918.0000,4513.4100) .. controls
          (4028.6900,4423.1200) and (4483.9500,4164.6400) .. (4908.3600,4124.5600) ..
          controls (4990.6300,4116.7700) and (5261.0700,4109.0100) ..
          (5505.4800,4238.1600)(6034.6500,4501.2800) .. controls (5723.9500,4524.5700)
          and (5045.2600,4657.5900) .. (4644.2700,4796.4400) .. controls
          (4622.8900,4612.4500) and (4240.3600,4629.4300) .. (4240.3600,4629.4300) ..
          controls (4240.3600,4629.4300) and (5001.8000,4307.7900) ..
          (5564.7200,4291.5500) .. controls (5699.4100,4287.6700) and
          (5903.8200,4333.3100) .. (6034.6500,4501.2800)(2905.0500,4528.4600) ..
          controls (2481.7100,4528.4600) and (2576.8800,4931.4000) ..
          (2576.8800,5012.9600) .. controls (2576.8800,5094.5100) and
          (2571.0500,5266.3700) .. (2308.4100,5234.3300) .. controls
          (2045.7700,5202.2900) and (1598.1700,4925.5800) .. (1444.7600,4823.6300) ..
          controls (1440.8800,4753.7200) and (1645.7400,4643.0300) ..
          (1921.4900,4677.9800) .. controls (1941.7400,4674.6400) and
          (2190.4900,4726.3900) .. (2206.9500,4720.2100) .. controls
          (2223.1000,4711.0000) and (2006.8200,4647.8500) .. (2016.5900,4642.7500) ..
          controls (2088.7700,4605.1000) and (2125.9000,4546.9000) ..
          (2182.6700,4532.3400) .. controls (2199.8400,4528.6000) and
          (2408.7700,4568.7100) .. (2441.4300,4555.6400) .. controls
          (2452.2600,4551.3200) and (2287.2300,4500.4600) .. (2298.7900,4495.4500) ..
          controls (2382.6900,4467.3000) and (2453.7700,4413.0600) ..
          (2486.8800,4382.0900) .. controls (2499.1100,4379.8400) and
          (2658.1800,4401.4800) .. (2671.0500,4399.3200) .. controls
          (2684.3900,4397.0800) and (2572.8600,4357.7300) .. (2586.5900,4355.6300) ..
          controls (2679.5800,4341.4300) and (2760.8800,4340.0900) ..
          (2812.8100,4340.0900) .. controls (2879.8100,4340.0900) and
          (2962.0900,4360.4900) .. (2998.9800,4340.0900) .. controls
          (3017.4300,4333.7100) and (2929.3300,4528.4600) ..
          (2905.0500,4528.4600)(2854.5600,4291.5500) .. controls (2843.2600,4283.8100)
          and (2828.9300,4272.8900) .. (2812.3200,4259.7000) .. controls
          (2895.3400,4228.4400) and (2959.9200,4153.1900) .. (2976.7700,4136.1900) ..
          controls (3019.0900,4223.8800) and (3001.8200,4317.0300) ..
          (3001.8200,4317.0300) .. controls (3001.8200,4317.0300) and
          (2898.7500,4321.1600) .. (2854.5600,4291.5500)(2473.9500,4340.0900) ..
          controls (2400.1700,4285.7200) and (1930.2100,4039.1100) ..
          (1804.0000,4000.2700) .. controls (1875.4700,3978.3300) and
          (1957.6600,3965.8000) .. (2039.8800,3961.6500) .. controls
          (2078.7800,4072.1200) and (2223.0500,4162.8300) .. (2308.4100,4204.6500) ..
          controls (2419.5900,4259.1300) and (2571.0500,4308.0600) ..
          (2775.9800,4273.0200) .. controls (2798.9700,4292.7800) and
          (2812.8100,4305.1500) .. (2812.8100,4305.1500) .. controls
          (2812.8100,4305.1500) and (2553.5600,4314.8500) ..
          (2473.9500,4340.0900)(2163.2600,4477.0000) .. controls (2067.1300,4412.9100)
          and (1595.2600,4142.0300) .. (1178.7300,4089.6000) .. controls
          (1333.1100,3949.7800) and (1651.3700,3988.4600) .. (1794.3000,4031.3400) ..
          controls (2017.6200,4098.3400) and (2441.4300,4356.1200) ..
          (2441.4300,4356.1200) .. controls (2441.4300,4356.1200) and
          (2276.8600,4501.7600) .. (2163.2600,4477.0000)(1860.3200,4631.3800) ..
          controls (1586.5200,4477.0000) and (913.6560,4273.1000) ..
          (529.1640,4238.1600) .. controls (581.5980,4162.4100) and (860.8550,4105.9200)
          .. (1126.2900,4124.5600) .. controls (1551.5600,4154.3900) and
          (2005.9700,4423.1200) .. (2116.6500,4513.4100) .. controls
          (2014.7000,4536.7100) and (2008.8800,4654.6800) ..
          (1860.3200,4631.3800)(1794.3000,4629.4300) .. controls (1794.3000,4629.4300)
          and (1033.0800,4291.5500) .. (469.9340,4291.5500) .. controls
          (353.4180,4291.5500) and (77.6758,4319.7000) .. (0.0000,4501.2800) .. controls
          (310.7070,4524.5700) and (989.3910,4657.5900) .. (1390.3800,4796.4400) ..
          controls (1411.7500,4612.4500) and (1794.3000,4629.4300) ..
          (1794.3000,4629.4300);
  \end{scope}
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]